# Cryptography sensitive information using spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

According to OWASP top 10 sensitive information like id need to be encrypted through the pass between clients and server. 
With spring how do that? 
I mean :
Is it possible with spring and how ? 
How generate keys?
Key vault needed (like oracle) or a key  generator ?

---

edit:

Example :

I write an API :
http://localhost:8080/Estate/api/estates/{id}

User 'A' can access to id 12 but I should prevent to access to id 14,15,16
So for that i should encrypt id .

Comment: Servlet container?  How a servlet container can do that?  How it can encrypt / decrypt an object 's ID in URL ?

Comment: @Teo Thanks but my problem is not encoding I should code sensitive information to prevent illegal access to database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As security base for a webapp you probably want to use HTTPS.

You can force Spring Security to use HTTPS with a config like this:

```xml
<http>
  <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" requires-channel="https"/>
  ...
</http>
```

This doesn't setup HTTPS for you, you will need to do it in Tomcat or the servlet container you use.

For a public valid server you need to order a certificate from a security company, for internal and testing you can create keystore using for example [Portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/).